# How to secure the html5 audio link from download

Tags: ios, html, wordpress, audio, code-access-security

I have a wordpress website in which I want to embed the audio player for .mp3 files. But the user should not get the server url of the music file.

Currently I have used [audio src=""]. But through this user get the url though page source. So is there any way or any plugin through which I can hide it in the page source.
Also I cannot use the flash player as it has to be run on iphone/ipad too.

Looking  forward for the replies

Comment: Have you tried any other solutions yet? Web Audio API for instance?

Comment: Actually I tried some plugins but none of that worked. So looking for any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with HTML5 audio and video is, that it directly links to the file.
This is also the reason sites like Netflix don't use it.
Only Microsoft Silverlight can protect your content from rippers properly.

BUT - you could use the dirty solution: Make an `<iframe>` and embed another html file that only contains your audio source and replace the body container with `<body oncontextmenu="return false">`

This will disable your users to open the context menu over your audio file and thus they will not be able to find the location of the file, however "html-pros" will just use f12 to open it.
If you only do it on this very limited part of the page, most people won't be able to get around this though. ;)